# Fragment Swipe Asynctask Disappearance?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a main activity and three fragments under it that can be switched by swiping left and right. Nothing special. The 1st and 3rd(last) fragment both use Asynctask to grap some info from online. What I'm trying to achieve here is three fragments that load up info from online and later on, I want to add in the pull down to refresh, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Here's what happens.

- When you open the app, its set to open the 2nd(middle) fragment.
- Upon swiping to the 3rd fragment, you'll see that everything loads up fine.
- Upon returning to the 2nd fragment and going back to the 3rd, it completely disappears and returns as a blank page.
- Now if I scroll twice back to the 1st fragment, and complete the network operation, it works fine.
- Try to do it again, the button doesn't reply.

I believe it has something to do with the Asynctask. If there's a better way to setup this whole thing I have here, then please feel free to do so.

**Main**

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);

    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }



        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
//          Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
//          Bundle args = new Bundle();
//          args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
//          fragment.setArguments(args);
//          return fragment;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // Top Rated fragment activity
                return new Post();
            case 1:
                // Games fragment activity
                return new Feed();
            case 2:
                // Movies fragment activity
                return new Explore();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Post";
            case 1:
                return "Feed";
            case 2:
                return "Explore";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**1st Fragment**

```
public class Post extends Fragment {
    private MyAsyncTask mAuthTask = null;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_post, container, false);


        Button addGoalButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit);
        addGoalButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                // Pass the fragmentView through to the handler
                // so that findViewById can be used to get a handle on
                // the fragments own views.
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

        public void attemptLogin() {

        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }


        mAuthTask = new MyAsyncTask();
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);

        }






    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
                    "dont worry, be happy!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           // my network operation


            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**3rd Fragment**

```
public class Explore extends Fragment {
    private MyAsyncTask mAuthTask = null;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_explore, container, false);
        attemptLogin();
        return rootView;
    }


public void attemptLogin() {

        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }           
        mAuthTask = new MyAsyncTask();
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }



    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
                    "Loading Explore", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           // my network operation



            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it a may be a couple issues.

1. Multiple Asynctasks cannot be run at the same time and with Viewpagers it loads 3 views by default. I believe you need to call: (whereever you don't want a code to be run for all the views which need to be loaded)

   ```
   if(getUserVisibleHint()) {
       //logic in here
       attemptLogin();
   }
   ```

I believe this will stop your onCreateView() method being called 3 times. So pretty much because a view pager has this method: `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);` which does this:

```
Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page
in the view hierarchy in an idle state.
```

By default it is at 1, which means if it will load the fragment to the left and right to make scrolling smooth. (You can't change this to 0). And so the getUserVisibleHint will check if the current view is the one the suer can see and call whatever stuff you put inside it, only when its visible. (because by default it would call your asynctask 3 times, and they cannot be run at the same time.

I may be wrong though.

Edit #1:
First fragment fixed by setting asynctask back to null in onPostExecute.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. attemptLogin(); didn't fire at all this time, and the 1st fragment button still fires only once.

Comment: How come you are calling `if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }` - try just call new MyAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);, without checking if it is null or not. That might be why the button is  not working after you do it again and why its a white screen on the third fragment, because it might have something to do with you checking if asynctask is null. - Also try search your code up in github, a lot of similar code like: https://github.com/rabinv/ordboken/blob/0955d7c576c939cf22bd139ebdb581e37ce191b1/src/in/rab/ordboken/LoginActivity.java

Comment: You will notice in his onPostExecute he sets the asynctask back to null, are you doing this? (because if you don't then it will only run once until the fragment is recreated) Also, put some log tags in your onPreexecute, onPostExecute, onDoInBackground methods for frag 1 and 3 and see if there is anything you can decipher from that. (Whether onPost is ever called etc.)

Comment: setting asynctask back to null worked like a charm for the first fragment!

Comment: For the third fragment, it loads once in view for the first time, after I swipe to the first fragment and go back to it again, it now encounters an app force close error

Comment: Care to post your logcat?

Comment: Line 31 and other lines with:  Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. suggest that you're trying to access views in doInBackground which you can't. Try move that logic into onPostExecute. Also, you can try the code in my point number 1 (getUserVisibleHint) and see if the error still occurs. To help you fix this, its better if you post the whole logic of the aSyncTask, as it looks like it can't be fixed with a broad general guess at the problem.

Comment: It seems that your right.. After removing the following code, everything works fine now.

ListView tweetList = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tListView);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
tweetList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
arrayAdapter.add("NETWORK_RESULT_VARIABLE");

Any idea on how to fix the following code above in order for it to work nicely with the Asynctask in doInBackground.